# Como desabilitar a listagem de diretório no WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, htaccess

Boa tarde a todos, gostaria que a minha listagem de diretórios não fosse exposta, usei o seguinte código dentro do **.htaccess** `Options -Indexes`, porém quando testo o código renomeando o **index.php** ele retorna **erro 403**. É possível apresentar uma outra tela de erro ou tem outra maneira de realizar este processo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sou especialista, e não sei se essa é exatamente a resposta que vc quer, mas vou te dar umas dicas do que eu já vi.

Primeiro no `robots.txt` do seu site desabilite os diretórios para que eles não apareçam em motores de busca, veja o exemplo: (o nome dos diretórios vai depender do que vc tem na raiz)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /administrator
Disallow: /cache/
Disallow: /cli/
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /images/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /language/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/
Disallow: /tmp/
```

Depois, crie um arquivo **index.html** em branco **na raiz de cada um desses diretórios**, assim se alguém tentar entrar direto pelo caminho da pasta vai cair em uma página em branco...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

E por último, tente "mascarar" que vc está usando o WordPress, remova ou renomeio os códigos que tenha escrito Wordpress, como por exemplo a `<meta name="generator" content="WordPress.com" />` no **`contente`** coloque o nome da sua empresa.

Answer (score 1):

Galera, depois de algumas pesquisas encontrei uma forma de não mostrar o meu diretório, segue o passo a passo:

//redirecionei o erro para uma imagem, onde indica site em manutenção, e usei o código abaixo para verificar//

`ErrorDocument 403 /`**site_em_manutencao.png**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(index|index/)$ index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php/$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```